# How to optimize Gaussian-process parameters for multiple tasks with GPML?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, gaussian-process

I have a lot of test curves and I want to optimize the length and scale parameters simultaneously for all curves.  Is this possible?

Comment: Are you asking how to do this with the [gpml MATLAB function](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/code/matlab/doc/)?

Comment: easiest way to do it is probably to assume independence and then just optimize the sum of the logliks. if you want to share information between processes look into multi-fidelity modeling with GPs.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a likelihood for the data in a usual way as far as I can understand.

Let we have data $D = \{X, Y\} = \{\mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{y}_i\}$_{i = 1}^{n} with $\mathbf{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^p$, and outputs $\mathbf{y}_i \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is multidimensional.
Denote by $\mathbf{y}^j = \{y_{1j}, y_{2j}, \ldots, y_{nj}\}$ - A vector which corresponds to $j$-th curve.

You suppose that each curve is a realization of a Gaussian process, but all Gaussian processes have zero mean value and the same covariance function $k(\mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{x}_j)$, so you get for each curve the loglikelihood of the the form:
$$
L(X, \mathbf{y}^j) = -\frac12 ( (\mathbf{y}^j)^T K^{-1} \mathbf{y}^j + \log |K| +  n \log (2 \pi)),
$$
here $K = \{k(\mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{x}_j)\}_{i, j = 1}^{n}$ is a sample covariance matrix.
And the joint likelihood is a product of separate likelihoods, so we can use common techniques to optimize it. For example, for most covariance functions we can calculate derivatives w.r.t covariance function parameters and use a derivative-based optimization.

Comment: I think $|K|$ should be replaced by $\log |K|$